# Webview URL items not Visble

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio, url, android-webview

I have a android studio Project with a Webview and a Nav Bar and with the Nav bar I can change between WebViews.

My Problem is that when I but something in my ShoppingCard and switch with the Nav bar to my Shopping Card the Items in there are not Visble how can I solve, this? the ShoppingCard URL ends with .php if this helps

Best Regards T.S

Comment: why multiple WebViews ?

Comment: Because my Client want to have multiple WebViews‍♂️ Any idea how to fix the error Sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
[image]

just created a tiny app with two tabs which change two webviews. TAB 1 webview show cart items, other one (TAB 2) show product listing , from product listing i can add product and cart page auto reloaded/refreshed using AndroidCartApp (a JavascriptInterface ) class, and i can see added items in carts, there is no such issue, in this app, other than tabs all is under webviews/htmlapp , maybe you are adding items to cart in other way,

Comment: Thank you, worked for Android but could you manage to look inside this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547107/xcode-wkwebview-not-loading